# Docker : Visualization tool for Images dependencies (child images, grandchildren...)

Tags: gratis, virtualization, docker, visualization

I have a lot of Docker images installed. Some of them are from hub.docker.com, and were created by others. Often I don't understand them in depth. I have customized a few of these Docker images, by tweaking the default configuration *inside the container*, changing some files, added plugins to apps, etc.

Then I have created new images with the `docker commit` command.

Now when I try to delete an image with the `docker image remove`  command, I get errors. Something like `Image cannot be deleted because some other image depends on it.` And when I delete those, the same error message appears. Thus, some images have grandchildren.

**Is there a visualization tool that finds and displays all dependencies among images?** Then it should try to find secondary, tertiary dependencies as well. It would be cool if it also displayed the  names of dependent *containers* .

The output should be something like a family tree for images and containers (if possible). It could be ascii-art, pixel grahics or vector graphics.

I just want to use this tool for personal purposes, it does not have to be production quality; no need for fancy collaboration features. It should be free and should run on Linux)